# access outside variable in macro?

Tags: freemarker

how to access `main` namespace variable in macro?

I have a macro file called `orderMacro.ftl`, and import it in `test.ftl` like this:

```
<#import "path/orderMacro.ftl" as order/>
```

I also define a variable in `test.ftl`:

```
<#assign orderType="normal"/>
```

Now I access `orderType` variable in `orderMacro` using `main.orderType`, `main` means the namespace created for `test.ftl`(maybe I misunderstand this word).
it reports an error: `Expression main is undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `.main.orderType`. Note the initial dot. It's the syntax for accessing "special variables", so that they can't clash with other variables.

Comment: here "test.ftl" has the namespace defined as "main". What if there are no  namespace defined. In that case How to access/update variable defined in "test.ftl" from "ordermacro.ftl". I dont want to use global.

Comment: @NoOne The `main` namespace is automatically defined, and always exists.

Answer (score 1):

Assign it using global

http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_global.html

```
<#global orderType="normal"/>
```